# How to check if a specific user has a role? Discord js

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js, roles

I know how to check if the message sender has a role:

```
if(message.member.roles.has(role.id)) {
  console.log(`Yay, the author of the message has the role!`);
} else {
  console.log(`Nope, noppers, nadda.`);
}
```

However, how can I check if specific user (using user id) has a specific role?

```
    var authorID = "111111111111111111"

    //Find role
    var role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Private Splash Ping");
    //Find member
    let member = message.guild.members.get(authorID);

    console.log(member.roles.has(role))
    if(member.roles.has(role)) {
        roleadded = "User already has Private spalsh role."
    } else {
        message.member.addRole(role);
        roleadded = "Added private splash role."
    }
```

member.roles.has(role) always returns false and I've confirmed both member and role variables are correct via breakpoints.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Not familiar with discord.js, but if `roles` is an array, could you use `member.roles.indexOf(role)` instead of the `.has` method?

Comment: Are you receiving any errors? What version of discord.js are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`message.member.roles` is considered a GuildMemberRoleManager ([Documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager)), to access the collection of roles you must access the property `.cache` which is a collection. This collection then has the `.has(...)` method function. ([Documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=has))

Thus, you instead want to access `message.member.roles.cache.has(...)`